# In LibreOffice Writer how can I change the font of the numbers calling the footnotes?

Tags: libreoffice

In LibreOffice Writer how can I change the font of the numbers calling the footnotes ?

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice, all is controlled by styles. Modify the "Footnote Anchor" character style to change the appearance of the referring number in the text, and the "Footnote Characters" style to change the appearance of the footnote number in the footnote.

Comment: I know what Styles are and how to modify them, but I cannot modify the size of the font. May I add a file to this post to help illustrating my case ?

Comment: You cannot change the font size in a character style? Then indeed there must be something specific with your setup.

Comment: Ok. How can I reinstall this set up ?